# $\delta$-fined division and Lebesgue measure $\mu$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $E$ be a measurable subset of $[0,1]$. Then we know that we can choose an open set $G$ and a closed set $F$ such that $F\subset E \subset G \subset [0,1]$. For each $t\in [0,1]$, define

$$\delta(t) = 
 \begin{cases}
\text{dist}(t,G^c),&\text{if $t\in F$}\\
\text{min}\{\text{dist}(t,b(G)),\text{dist}(t,F)\},&\text{if $t\in G\smallsetminus F$}\\
\text{dist}(t,F),&\text{if $t\in [0,1]\smallsetminus G$.}  
 \end{cases} 
$$

Here we use the notation $b(G)$ to mean the boundary of $G$. Because the sets $G^c$, $b(G)$, and $F$ are closed, it follows that $\delta(t)>0$ for each $t\in [0,1].$ This defines a positive function $\delta$ defined on $[0,1].$ Cousin's Lemma therefore assures that a division $D=\{(t_i,I_i)\}_{i=1}^{n}$ exists such that for each $i=1,\dots,n$ we have $t_i\in [0,1]$ and

$$I_i\subset (t_i-\delta(t_i),t_i+\delta(t_i)).$$

Some authors call $D$ as a $\delta$-fined free tagged division of $[0,1].$

**My question:**

How do we show (if it is true) that

$$(D)\sum_{t_i\in E}[\mu(I_i)-\mu(E\cap I_i)] \leq \mu(G\smallsetminus F)$$ and

$$(D)\sum_{t_i\notin E}\mu(E\cap I_i)] \leq \mu(G\smallsetminus F)$$

where $\mu$ denotes the Lebesgue measure.

Any tips?Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The choice of $\delta$ implies the following two properties of the tagged partition $(t_i,I_i)$: 
$$t_i\in G\implies I_i\subseteq G \tag{1}$$
$$t_i\notin F\implies I_i\cap F=\varnothing \tag{2}$$

Since the intervals form a partition of $[0,1]$, property (1) implies
$$\sum_{t_i\in G} \mu(I_i) \le \mu(G)\tag{3}$$
and property (2) implies
$$\sum_{t_i\in G} \mu(F\cap I_i) = \mu(F)\tag{4}$$
Therefore, 
$$\sum_{t_i\in G} (\mu(I_i) - \mu(F\cap I_i)) \le \mu(G\setminus F)\tag{5}$$
which is stronger than the your first inequality.

If $t_i\notin F$, then by (2) $E\cap I_i\subseteq G\setminus F$. Therefore,
$$\sum_{t_i\notin F} \mu(E\cap I_i)\le \mu(G\setminus F)\tag{6}$$ 
which is stronger than your second inequality.

Comment: I still have to verify(if I can do it)the 6 inequalities.:)Much better if you can add some details. Anyway, many many thanks to you. I have already an answer to the problem but it seems that your answer is simpler and nice.

Comment: @jum But if I add more details, they  will involve more inequalities, which will also need to be verified. That will call for more inequalities, and so on to infinity...

Comment: I understand. Do not be bothered. The suggested inequalities are already enough.

Comment: As of this time, I can follow everything except (4). Maybe later I can fix it. I take a break first.:)

Comment: @jun I made a mistake in (4) and (5): edited now. Let me know if anything else is unclear.

Comment: Thanks. I can now go back to (4) again. (5) has nothing to worried. It follows from (3) and (4) and by measurability of $E$. I am hanging a little bit on (4).

Comment: That (4) is something I cannot verify. Maybe I cannot find the tricks...

Comment: @jun The set $F$ is covered by intervals $I_i$. The intervals with $t_i\notin F$ do not participate in this, since they do not intersect $F$ by (2). Therefore, our summation over $i$ such that $t_i\in G$ includes all intervals that intersect $F$. Equality (4) follows by additivity of measure: the measure of $F$ is equal to the sum of measures of the pieces $F\cap I_i$ into which it is divided.

Comment: I got it.:) Thanks for sharing your time.